# how can i show that (cost,sint,t) is not affine variety and find its zariski closure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

how can i prove that the set X={(cost,sint,t): t belongs to R} a sub set of R^3 is not an affine variety? can i write X as (x,y,z) and then use nullestellensatz to find whole R^3 as zariski closure of X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the first part, a semi-dirty trick is as follows: Consider a suitable line $L$ such that $X \cap L$ is infinite, but not the whole line $L$. Why does an existence of such a line prove that $X$ is not Zariski closed?

As for the second part: there is one nice relation that your set $X$ satisfies:  we have $(\cos t)^2+(\sin t)^2=1$, so $X \subseteq V:=\{ (x, y, z) \; |\; x^2+y^2=1\}$. Try to show that $V$ is the Zariski closure of $X$. One approach is to mimic the line argument as above.

Comment: i think from fundamental theorem of algebra but how to know such a line exists?

Comment: I think for that it would be most useful to visualize $X$. If you do not realize how it looks like, a picture is e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix#Mathematical_description). I don't see how you intend to use the fundamental theorem of algebra, especially since you work over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: i wanted to use it after finding such a line over R^2 and then parametrizing it and work over R...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the fundamental theorem of algebra - it usually refers to the statement that nonzero complex polynomials have a complex root. What you need instead is the fact that a nonzero polynomial has at most finitely many roots, or in other words, that the closed sets in the Zariski topology on a line are precisely the finite sets, and the whole line.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg But $X \neq V$. For each $t$, there is only one point in the intersection $X \cap \{(x, y, z)\;|\; z=t\},$ whereas $V \cap \{(x, y, z)\;|\; z=t\}\simeq S^1$ is infinite. I guess what you are thinking of is $X'=\{(\cos t, \sin t, s)\;|\; t \in \mathbb{R}, s \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

Comment: Dear Pavel, you are right: sorry for my unfair comment, now deleted. And +1 for your fine answer.